# Ext groups and Isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra

Let $A$ and $B$ be abelian groups. Let $\mathrm{Ext}(A, B) = 0$, and let $C$ and $D$ be group with $C\cong A$ and $D\cong B$. Does this imply $\mathrm{Ext}(C, D) = 0$?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that is true - besides than the fundamental observation that there's no reason why the specific elements of a group would matter, so any isomorphic copy of a group is as good as any other for this purpose, you can make an obvious bijection between SES's
$$0\to A\to X\to B\to0$$
and SES's
$$0\to C\to X\to D\to0$$
using the isomorphisms $A\cong C$ and $B\cong D$, and it passes to a bijection between equivalence classes of SES's, hence of $\mathrm{Ext}$ groups. (We actually never need to use that $\mathrm{Ext}(A,B)=0$.)

Comment: Thanks @ Zev Chonoles.  So when $0\rightarrow A \rightarrow  X\rightarrow B \rightarrow 0$ splits, then $0\rightarrow C \rightarrow X \rightarrow D \rightarrow 0$ splits with the condition $A\cong C$ and $B\cong D.$

Comment: Yup, that's right.